# Get List of Filenames from sub-folders and assign it to database column name adf

Tags: azure-data-factory

I need to get the json filename and assign it to a column in my database. I got 2 sub-folders currently.

> ParentFolder/SubFolder00/**filename1.Json** ParentFolder/SubFolder00/**filename2.Json** ParentFolder/SubFolder00/**filename3.Json** ParentFolder/SubFolder01/**filename1.Json** ParentFolder/SubFolder01/**filename2.Json** ParentFolder/SubFolder01/**filename3.Json**

Database Table: (Data to be inserted to the table is read from each json files.)

name | date | filename

I tried to use:

Get Metadata1 (for sub folders) -> ForEach SubFolders

then inside Foreach;
Get Metadata2 (files per sub folder)

I tried to append the array result to a variable but appending arrays are not supported. I need to loop through the Get Metadata2 to append the files individually, but loop inside a loop is also not supported.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: For nested foreach loops, you will need a second pipeline. The first pipeline gets the list of folders and passes the folder name to the second pipeline which gets the list of files.

Comment: Yup, I tried this idea and it worked. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> loop inside a loop is also not supported.

Yes, loop inside loop is not supported. in ADF

As you want Data to be inserted to the table is read from each Json files and file name should get stored

Agreed with Joel Cochran you need to first iterate through the Parent folder and get subfolders then pass this folder name to another pipeline as a parameter.

- Dataset of Parent folder
  [image]
- Get metadata to get subfolders.
  [image]
- Pass it to for each activity
  [image]
- Pass this folder name to another pipeline as a parameter.
  [image]

Then in that pipeline Iterate through this folder and get files name in and use it to copy the data and file name.

- Parameter of second pipeline
  [image]
- Dataset of sub folder
  [image]
- Get metadata to get files.
  [image]
- pass it to Foreach loop and under for each loop take copy activity and source setting of it
  [image]
- sink setting of the copy activity.
  [image]

**Output:**

[image]